# pg_trgm (fuzzy search) on concated index

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, indexing

I have a question about indexes, and more specific about fuzzy search.
I found a medium [article](https://dev.to/moritzrieger/build-a-fuzzy-search-with-postgresql-2029) but idk if it is outdated or not.

Anyway my question is, if I create an index with a function:
CREATE INDEX search_gin_trgm_idx ON test
USING gin (f_immutable_concat_ws("first name", "last name", "birthday") gin_trgm_ops);

and then as the article does search a similarity using pg_trgm
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE 'je' <% f_immutable_concat_ws("first name", "last name", "birthday");

Why do I call the function again? or does it then recognize this as the index?
Is the index not created on all the columns when I create it?
When I insert more data, will the index also be created on them?

Like what I expected was more smth with the index name
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE 'je' <% search_gin_trgm_idx;

(also as a followup, can I create the index on columns from multiple tables together?)

Comment: "Why do I call the function again?"  As opposed to what?

Comment: As opposed to what I provided in the 2nd last paragraph...